# повесить на Button отработку нажатия какой либо кнопки softkeyboard'а

Tags: android, kotlin, button, android-softkeyboard

Есть EditText в него записывается все что вводиться с кнопок Button. Но это не кастомная клавиатура, а именно что отработка кнопок, реализовал вроде все. То есть кнопки отрабатывают как если бы писал с клавиатуры. Естественно что столкнулся с проблемами которых наверное не было если бы использовал кастомную клавиатуру. И задался вопросом. Можно ли сделать так что бы повестить, к примеру на мою кнопку backspace клавиатурное нажатие backspace.

Comment: отрезайте у строки в EditText последний символ по нажатию на ваш "кастомный backspace" =) Вы там на свои прочие кнопки что-то прибавляете к строке находящейся в EditText, ну а на backspace отрезайте)

Comment: спасибо за совет. Но это уже все сделано. Мне именно интересно, можно ли сделать полноценный бэкспэйс на клавише.

Comment: Виртуальная клавиатура - по сути эмуляция физической. Вы можете точно так же слать KeyEvent'ы - но поверьте, напрямую с текстом работать проще.